# Notepad++ : How to Delete every line starting with string + the previous line

Tags: notepad++

I want a code in Notepad++ that deletes every line starting with a certain string and also the preceeding line

EG : Delete every line **starting** with

> http://atlantisiptv.com:8080/lisa/lisa1

And the **previous** line

## From :

```
#EXTINF:-1,AS* | Max HD2
http://atlantisiptv.com:8080/lisa/lisa1/116204
#EXTINF:-1,H265
http://jokeriptv.online:1453/ferhat2/27022019/125554
#EXTINF:-1,AS*Max HD1
http://atlantisiptv.com:8080/lisa/lisa1/116203
#EXTINF:-1,H265
http://jokeriptv.online:1453/ferhat2/27022019/125553
#EXTINF:-1,H265
http://jokeriptv.online:1453/ferhat2/27022019/125552
#EXTINF:-1,AS*HD3
http://atlantisiptv.com:8080/lisa/lisa1/116565
#EXTINF:-1,AS*HD
http://atlantisiptv.com:8080/lisa/lisa1/104915
#EXTINF:-1,H265
http://jokeriptv.online:1453/ferhat2/27022019/125551
#EXTINF:-1,AS*HD4
http://atlantisiptv.com:8080/lisa/lisa1/116564
```

## To :

```
#EXTINF:-1,H265
http://jokeriptv.online:1453/ferhat2/27022019/125554
#EXTINF:-1,H265
http://jokeriptv.online:1453/ferhat2/27022019/125553
#EXTINF:-1,H265
http://jokeriptv.online:1453/ferhat2/27022019/125552
#EXTINF:-1,H265
http://jokeriptv.online:1453/ferhat2/27022019/125551
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps with a macro https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2013/10/27/notepad-macros-example/, but I have no idea what "_a code in Notepad++_" might mean. You can record a macro, not sure it is possible to code one directly.  You could of course write code to operate on the text file in any number of programming languages, but that does not appear to be what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use search and replace to replace `.*\r\nhttp://atlantisiptv\.com:8080/lisa/lisa1.*(\r\n)?` with nothing. Turn on regex mode and turn off `. matches new line`

If you aren't using windows line endings change `\r\n` to `\n`

Comment: how can I Turn on regex mode ?

Comment: Check the "regular expression" radio button in the "search mode" box?